# DC comics in Arrowverse?

Tags: analysis, reference, arrowverse, the-flash

In *The Flash* S04E17  *Null and Annoyed*, there is a [conversation](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=the-flash-2014&episode=s04e17) between Ralph and Barry as such:

> An improv group made up of superheroes? We can take it to Washington.
>   - We'd be the DC Comics.
>   - No, Ralph.

Usually the Arrowverse shows reference Marvel comics and it could be taken as the comic medium that the DC universe people reads... However, how does the "DC" universe have **DC comics**? Is this an oversight from the showrunners or are they referencing another DC comics that I do not know about?

### TLDR: How does DC Comics exist in the DC universe (or) Are they referencing another DC comics?

Comment: They'd be the "DC Comics" because they're going to Washington DC.

Comment: @phantom42 Ahh...Wordplay... Got it! :D

Comment: isn't that in MCU, marvel comics were shown multiple times?

Comment: @Vishwa are you talking about the movie Logan?

Comment: @AbhishekMishra that being one

Comment: *"Usually the Arrowverse shows reference Marvel comics"* Can you provide some examples of this?

Comment: @faintsignal Flash season 4 is more overt with Marvel references... Off the top of my head, Caitlin was referred to as Hulk since she is both Caitlin/Killer frost and Barry says his spidey-senses are tingling when he doubts about Devoe and so .on...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is entirely possible that they tried to make a joke or word play out of "DC" in Washington DC.

Or

Arrowverse, specifically the Flash show, have shown the concept of Multiverse to be true.

And remember, they do not mention that they are in the universe where DC comics do not exist. They seem closer to what our universe would be like if it had superheroes.

Since Multiverse is vast (in Arrowverse), it is very likely that our superheroes are in one where we have DC Comics.

The more likely reason may also be due to the fact that the showrunners try to be very cheeky and want to throw in as many pop culture references in the show as possible.

Comment: I'd add that in season 1 or 2, upon setting a Flash signal, Cisco said something along the lines of "must have read that in a comics". One would wonder which comic would feature such a thing, don't you think? ;)

Comment: Can't edit the previous comment, so [here it is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QDkSZVfPBDE), starting at 1m9s.

Comment: That was a nice moment. So sad I had to stop watching this series because of that annoying Iris.